# SvnKit export failed randomly on linux

Tags: java, ubuntu, svnkit

I am using svnkit to export subversion repositories. I am using the code from https://gist.github.com/cliffdarling/2360866 with slight modifications that related to reading command line arguments. I am running this on ubuntu 16. subversion server use windows authentication. when I run the code I get following exception time to time.

`org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for 'https://subversion.myserver.com:443' at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:53) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.authenticationFailed(SVNErrorManager.java:47) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.getNextAuthentication(DefaultSVNAuthenticationManager.java:233) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:724) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:391) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:862) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:698) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:118) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1049) at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.getLatestRevision(DAVRepository.java:189)`

Java code is run by a bash script and it loops through a list of urls. I use the vm option -Dsvnkit.http.methods=Digest,Basic,NTLM,Negotiate. jar file is executed as follows.

`java -Dsvnkit.http.methods=Digest,Basic,NTLM,Negotiate -jar exporter.jar url`

Code works for some repo urls but failed sometimes. It is randomly happen. Code works without a problem in windows. I could not find out a solution for this. why does happening ?